# Regex remove URLs paths and keep last slug of the URLs

Tags: regular-expression

I have a file that has different HTML tags inside it and multiple img src URLs spread out across it:

```
<img src="https://www.example.com/parent-folder-1/subfolder-1/image1.png">
<img src="https://www.example.com/parent-folder-2/subfolder-2/image2.png">
...
<img src="https://www.example.com/parent-folder-100/subfolder-100/image100.png">
```

I've mentioned `parent-folder-N` just to have an idea, there's no specific pattern to these URLs, they might all have different subfolders BUT they have the same URL at the beginning as the source `https://www.example.com/`

I am trying to replace all the mentions of `https://www.example.com/parent-folder-N/subfolder-N/imageN.png` with the local path `imageN.png`, so all these would become:

```
<img src="image1.png">

<img src="image2.png">
...
<img src="image100.png">
```

So basically it would look at the full URL path and ONLY keep the last slug which is `imageN.png`.

For example these are the URLs parts that I am trying to Find with Regex `https://i.imgur.com/u9JgF6B.png` and replace with `[nothing]`, so in the end I am left only with the `imageN.png` slugs.

**Is it possible somehow to accomplish this using Regex?**

PS: I tried using a regex expression like this `^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]example+)\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$` and this matches example.com but I don't know how to match the URL path after `example.com/...` until the last `/` before `imageN.png`

PPS: the images always can have the extension `.png` or `.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know what you mean for *using regex* but this is how to do that with `sed` :

```
sed 's!https://www.example.com/.*/!!' file.html
```

Or (Assuming your link dosnt hold a `!` character):

```
sed '/https:\/\/www.example.com\//{y@/@|@;s/".*|/"/}' test
```

Use the `-i` option (Availabe in `Gnu sed`) to apply changes to the html file.

---

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's@(?:https://www.example.com/.*/)(.*[.])(png|jpg)@$1$2@' test.html
```

`perl` to have the `-i` option to enable edit directly in the file.

Comment: thanks a lot @DanieleGrassini ! this worked great on the command line too! I did not know I can use sed for this, it's beautiful! I did a tweak to it to apply to all html files I'd have in a folder and also applied the changes to the files `sed -i '/https:\/\/www.example.com\//{y@/@|@;s/".*|/"/}' *.html` 

Thank you so much!

Comment: @ DanieleGrassini would it be possible to use the sed command to replace the URL path across all `<img ...>` html tags no matter what domain is in the URL path, and keep the last slug? so for instance in the above command it is only `www.example.com`; if there are different domains in the URL path, different than `www.example.com`, would I be able to use a similar sed command, remove all of the URL paths and only keep the last slug of the URL paths?

Comment: @Lernisios sorry for being late.
Yes, but the task become quite harder to be done with `regular expression` and such tools. You should think to switch to a language with an `HTML` library parsing such as `perl` or `python`.

Comment: thanks a lot @ DanieleGrassini , got it!

Comment: I was trying to use the `perl` command you mentioned across multiple files but didn't work that well. I have different domains in the img scr URLs paths, like `https://www.example.com, https://www.example1.com, https://www.example2.com` etc. So I digged into it and saw someone trying to do something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864143/strip-out-the-last-url-name-in-string but did not get it to work on my end. Would it be possible somehow with `perl` to keep the last slug of the `<img src=..` URLs? (no matter if last slug is `.png` or `.jpg`)?

Comment: The `perl` wont work since it is written for your original answer where the domain is `www.example.com` and not `www.example[0-9].com`

Comment: If i understand well your comment try :

```sed 's@<img src="https://www.example[0-9]*.com/.*/@<img src="@' file.html```

Otherwise please post a new questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm by far no expert with regex, but this should work:

`(http).*\/`

---

#### Explanation

`(http)` matches on the string "http"

`.*` matches any characters 0 or more times until

`\/` matches the last slash.

Comment: thanks for that @mashuptwice. It seems the regex is matching the last path of the URL `https://regex101.com/r/D2Erau/1` but what I need to do is match the path before it and keep only the last slug. So it should match only everything that is before the last slug (path) of the URL

This is what I mean `https://i.imgur.com/u9JgF6B.png`

Comment: @Lernisios sorry, I was just looking at the path, completely ignoring the HTML tag

Comment: I've edited the answer with the correct regex for your usecase. I hope I got you right this time

Comment: it worked like a charm, I did do a tweak to it `(https://www.example.com).*\/` so it will only apply for that specific URL, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure, was a nice opportunity to learn a bit regex again